# Teamcity error: The session is not authenticated. Access denied

Tags: web, teamcity

When I try to install jdbc driver(via Teamcity web interface), and then click on Refresh button I see next notification:
"The session is not authenticated. Access denied."

Why is it happens?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

My experience with this was that the session had expired.  It appears that it wants this done in a relatively short order.  I had it on a VM and parked it overnight before I started configuring, and got the error. A fresh build did not present this error.